# How to print a string in a Label's caption?

Tags: delphi

I have a form with a label, in which I want to put the variable 'accuracy' of type Real along with the symbol '%' (e.g. in format 57,49%). Is that even possible with a Label? I tried googling but didn't find anything relevant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Label1.Caption := Format('%.2f%%', [accuracy]);
```

The second `%` escapes the percent symbol and treats it as a part of the actual string (and not a format string).